# ERC20 "transferFrom" not transferring balance/token to contract address

Tags: exchanges, decentralization, transferfrom

I am trying to make a DEX and facing an issue in swapping. I created two contracts. One is Token (of ERC20 type) and other is Exchange. Here is my Token contract.

```
contract Token is ERC20 {
    address public owner;

    constructor(string memory _name,string memory _symbol,uint256 initialSupply) ERC20(_name, _symbol) {
        owner = msg.sender;
        _mint(msg.sender,  initialSupply );
    }

    function getOwner() public view returns (address) {
        return owner;
    }
}
```

My Exchange contract is

```
contract Exchange is ERC20 {
    using Counters for Counters.Counter;
    
    address public owner;
    address public tokenAddress;
    uint256 exchangeBalance = 0;
    
    Counters.Counter private tokenIndex;
    mapping(uint256 => address) tokens;
    mapping(address => mapping(uint256 => uint256)) tokenBalancesForAddress;

    constructor() ERC20("Exchange", "EXC") {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }
    modifier onlyOwner {
        require(msg.sender == owner);
        _;
    }

    function getTokenIndex(address tokenContract) internal view returns (uint) {
        uint tokenCount = tokenIndex.current();
        for (uint i = 1; i <= tokenCount; i++) {
            if (tokenContract == tokens[i]) {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }

    function getExchangeBalance() public view returns (uint256) {
        return exchangeBalance;
    }

    // Only admin function
    function addToken(address tokenContract) public onlyOwner {
        tokenIndex.increment();
        uint256 tokenId = tokenIndex.current();
        tokens[tokenId] = tokenContract;
    }

    function depositToken(address tokenContract, uint256 amount) public {
        uint256 index = getTokenIndex(tokenContract);
        require(IERC20(tokenContract).transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), amount));
        uint256 currentBalance = tokenBalancesForAddress[msg.sender][index];

        tokenBalancesForAddress[msg.sender][index] = currentBalance + amount;

        uint256 contractBalance = getExchangeBalance();
        exchangeBalance = contractBalance + amount;
        console.log("Balance of this: ", exchangeBalance);
    }

    function withdrawToken(address tokenContract, uint256 amount) public {
        uint256 index = getTokenIndex(tokenContract);

        uint tokenBalance = tokenBalancesForAddress[msg.sender][index];
        require(tokenBalance >= amount, "token amount less than sender token balance");
        tokenBalancesForAddress[msg.sender][index] = tokenBalance - amount;

        IERC20 token = IERC20(tokens[index]);
        require(token.transfer(msg.sender, amount));
    }

    function getBalanceToken(address tokenContract) public view returns (uint256) {
        uint256 index = getTokenIndex(tokenContract);
        // console.log("Token index: %d, Balance: %d", index, tokenBalancesForAddress[msg.sender][index]);
        return tokenBalancesForAddress[msg.sender][index];
    }

    function getBalanceUser(address _Useraddress, address tokenContract) public view returns (uint256) {
        uint256 index = getTokenIndex(tokenContract);
        // console.log("Token index: %d, Balance: %d", index, tokenBalancesForAddress[msg.sender][index]);
        return tokenBalancesForAddress[_Useraddress][index];
    }

    function ethToTokenSwap(address fromContract, uint256 _minTokens) public payable {
        console.log("Balance of contract: ", address(fromContract).balance);
        uint256 fromBalance = getBalanceToken(fromContract);
        require(fromBalance >= _minTokens, "Not enough token to transfer");
        IERC20(fromContract).transfer(msg.sender, _minTokens);
        console.log("Amount transferred");
    }

    function tokenToEthSwap(address fromContract, uint256 _minEth) public {
        uint256 fromBalance = getBalanceToken(fromContract);
        console.log("fromBalance: %d", fromBalance);
        require(fromBalance >= _minEth, "Not enough ethers to transfer");
        IERC20(fromContract).transferFrom(msg.sender,address(this),_minEth);
        payable(msg.sender).transfer(_minEth);
    }
}
```

Deployed two Token contract and added to exchange.

```
const token1 = await Token.deploy("Ethereum", "ETH", 1000);
const token2 = await Token.deploy("DAI Token", "DAI", 5000);
  
await token1.deployed();
await token2.deployed();
exchange.addToken(token1.address);
exchange.addToken(token2.address);
```

From front end i am approving and "exchange.depositToken" to exchange and using allowance to allow exchange to transfer. Then when i call `await dex_Contract.ethToTokenSwap(exchangeaddress, tokenAmount);` it reverted with reason " reverted with reason string 'ERC20: transfer amount exceeds balance'" and balance in "ethToTokenSwap" shows 0 although i have transferred token using "deposit" method.

Regards.

Comment: Can you share all your smart contract code?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Updated the question's details.